# Unable to fetch data using external data source

Tags: azure, powershell, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to fetch values from azure using external data source in terraform.  However, i dont understand what am i doing wrong when i try to export values using write-output, getting an error

> data.external.powershell_test: data.external.powershell_test: command "Powershell.exe" produced invalid JSON: invalid character 'l' looking for beginning of object key string"

Below is my script

```
$vm=(Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName MFA-RG -Name vm2).name | convertTo-json
Write-Output "{""first"" : ""$vm""}"
```

Main.tf file

```
data "external" "powershell_test" {
  program = ["Powershell.exe", "./vm.ps1"]
}

output "value" {
  value = "${data.external.powershell_test.result.first}"
}
```

Can someone tel me what wrong with the script ? and if i am using write-out properly ?

Edited-------------

Below is the screenshot when i run vm.ps1 directly
[image]

Also, when i directly assign value to a variable as below, terraform is able to execute the code.

```
$vm = "testvm"
Write-Output "{""first"" : ""$vm""}"
```

[image]

Comment: What does the output look like if you run the `vm.ps1` script directly?

Comment: I have edited the post with the details you asked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your issue, you should change your PowerShell command like this:

```
$vm=(Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName MFA-RG -Name vm2).name | convertTo-json
Write-Output "{""first"" : $vm}"
```

And you could change the code in the data source like this or not, but I suggest you do this:

```
data "external" "powershell_test" {
      program = ["Powershell.exe", "${path.module}/vm.ps1"]
    }
```

The result on my side is below:

[image]

I use the new Azure PowerShell module Az and my code shows here:

PowerShell:

```
$vm=(Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName charles -Name azureUbuntu18).name | convertTo-json
Write-Output "{""first"" : $vm}"
```

Terraform:

```
data "external" "powershell_test" {
  program = ["Powershell.exe", "${path.module}/vm.ps1"]
}

output "value" {
  value = "${data.external.powershell_test.result.first}"
}
```

Comment: Thank you charles, your solution worked after installing Az module !!
 can you please tell me why same thing wasn't working on AzureRM module ?

Comment: @user2549572 You also can do that through AzureRM module. The problem is that when you refer the VM in your Powershell, you'd better just change your code as I said in the answer.

Comment: But when i try using the code you shared of AzureRM module, it gives the same error but changing code to Az module works

Comment: @user2549572 You can check if the AzureRM module gives you the thing as you expected.

Comment: When i run the vm.ps1 directly with AzureRM module it gives desired output ({"first" : "VM2"}) but when i run terraform apply , it gives the error 
   (data.external.powershell_test: data.external.powershell_test: command "Powershell.exe" produced invalid JSON)

Comment: @user2549572 Not the terraform plan gives the error? And the output of the vm.ps1 is `{"first" : "VM2"}`, not `{"first" : ""VM2""}`? And do you change your PowerShell code? I can use the AzureRM module on my side correctly.

Comment: Dont know whats wrong...output of vm.ps1 is {"first" : "VM2"} and terraform plan too gives the same error, could it be something related to powershell/.net version ?

Comment: @user2549572 I don't know how can it happen. But I would add the command `Enable-AzureRmAlias` at the beginning of the PowerShell script when using the AzureRM module if the Az module is installed. I think everything would be OK if you can get the VM name through the AzureRM module and the Az module gets the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

`data.external.powershell_test.result` is the only valid attribute, and it is map.

So the code will be changed to

```
output "value" {
  value = "${data.external.powershell_test.result['first']}"
}
```

Reference:

https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/interpolation.html#user-map-variables

Comment: this doesn't appear to be formatted correctly for me. I get this error: parse error at 1:38: expected expression but found invalid sequence "'"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks *Charles XU* for the answer. I was looking for Azure Application Gateway and after lots of digging I ended up here, as Terraform is yet to provide a data source for Azure Application Gateway. However, the same can be done using shell script and azure rest API.

**Using Shell Script**

***appgw.sh***

```
#!/bin/bash

#Linux: Requires Azure cli and jq to be available

#Getting Application Gateway ID using azure application gateway rest API, az cli as data source doesn't exist for it.
appgwid=$(az rest -m get --header "Accept=application/json" -u 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/newrg/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways?api-version=2020-07-01' | jq '.value[].id')

#Terraform External Data Source requires an output, else it will return in unmarshal json error with }
echo "{\"appgw_id\" : $appgwid}"
```

***data.tf***

```
data "external" "appgw_id_sh" {
      program = ["/bin/bash", "${path.module}/appgw.sh"]
}
```

***outputs.tf***

```
output "appgw_id_sh" {
  value = data.external.appgw_id_sh.result.appgw_id
}
```

**Using Powershell**

***appgw.ps1***

```
#Windows: Require Azure Powershell to be available
#1. Install-Module -Name PowerShellGet -Force
#2. Install-Module -Name Az -AllowClobber

#Getting Application Gateway ID using AzApplicationGateway AzResource as data source doesn't exist for it.
$appGw = (Get-AzApplicationGateway -Name "appgw-name" -ResourceGroupName "appgw-rg-name").id | convertTo-json

#Terraform External Data Source requires an output, else it will return in unmarshal json error with }
Write-Output "{""appgw_id"" : $appgw}"
```

***data.tf***

```
data "external" "appgw_id_ps" {
      program = ["Powershell.exe", "${path.module}/appgw.ps1"]
}
```

***outputs.tf***

```
output "appgw_id_ps" {
  value = data.external.appgw_id_ps.result.appgw_id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI - when I use powershell 7, I need to use pwsh.exe instead of powershell.exe inside program code.

```
data "external" "powershell_test" {
  program = ["**pwsh.exe**", "${path.module}/vm.ps1"]
}
```