# Is it possible to upload files to Azure Share using terraform?

Tags: terraform, azure-storage, azure-storage-files

I use terraform to configure the storage account, containers, shares.

A question arised - can I upload a file to an Azure storage account file share with terraform? I cannot find the respective resource.

**EDIT 1**

An idea that comes is to use the `null_resource`. I wonder how it fits with the benefits of using terraform, which are in my opinion:

1. It can also be viewed as the documentation of your infrastructure.
2. It can tell you what it is about to do before doing it.
3. A variant of (2) - it gives you the ability to inspect the plan automatically and enforce policies.
4. Its state can be used to answer audit questions about what exactly has the release pipeline provisioned.
5. It has a very simple declarative language.

Other potential benefits could be enforcing the desired state, though, this is more potentially and in the future, rather than current. Indeed, try deleting a resource outside of terraform. In theory and in the future it could recognise it and recreate, today it just fails. But the potential is there.

All these benefits are enough to justify using it, even though I sometimes want to bang my head on the wall trying to do something with it.

Now, how all these benefits fit into running a custom script within a `null_resource`? Surely inspecting the plan would not help with a general purpose script inside a resource. I wonder how it fares against the other benefits?

Comment: Sure, first thing that comes to mind is using a null_resource

Comment: I never used it. What is the benefit of using `null_resource` over just running some script after terraform ends?

Comment: let me answer your question with a question... What is the benefit of using terraform over just running some scripts

Comment: @HelderSepulveda - please, see **EDIT 1**

Comment: That is a better question, I vote to reopen it...
have you look into the `Storage Resources` this one look like a good candidate: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/storage_blob.html

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean: inspecting the plan would not help with a general-purpose script inside a resource. ... if you code your null_resource correctly the plan will show valuable information on what files are new, changed or got removed

Comment: About your last comment - this is what I am missing. I need to understand how to write it correctly. An example would be super useful. It does not have to be about Azure, but if it shows off the correct usage of `null_resource` that would be valuable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone coming from Google, it's worth pointing out you should now be able to use azurerm_storage_share_file. This worked great for me to upload a single file. To upload multiple files it looks like you will require multiple resources

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/storage_share_file

```
resource "azurerm_storage_share_file" "example" {
  name             = "test.txt"
  storage_share_id = azurerm_storage_share.example.id
  source           = "${path.root}/TestFile/test.txt"
}
```

Comment: Nice thank you for the new suggestion, looks like that there is a bug on MD5 file change which re-creates the file, should be released on next run https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/11507

Answer (score 4):

Not sure I understood all your requirements. But, sure, it's possible to upload files to Azure Share using terraform.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61948833/how-to-copy-a-file-from-local-machine-to-a-storage-account-using-terraform/61950277#61950277) is a similar question about copying local files to Azure file share for your reference. The [local-exec provisioner](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/local-exec.html) allow you invoke a local executable PowerShell scripts after a resource is created. The [null_resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/null_resource.html) resource implements the standard resource lifecycle but takes no further action.

Sample,

```
 resource "azurerm_storage_share" "example" {
      name                 = "sharename"
      storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
      quota                = 50
    }

    resource "null_resource" "uploadfile" {

      provisioner "local-exec" {


      command = <<-EOT
      $storageAcct = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "${azurerm_resource_group.example.name}" -Name "${azurerm_storage_account.example.name}"
       Set-AzStorageFileContent `
       -Context $storageAcct.Context `
       -ShareName "${azurerm_storage_share.example.name}" `
       -Source "C:\Users\xxx\terraform\test.txt" `
       -Path "test.txt"

      EOT

      interpreter = ["PowerShell", "-Command"]
      }

}
```

Comment: What are the gotchas to this approach?

Comment: The `null_resource` are treated like normal resources but it does not provide any attributes or output as the normal resources.  If you want query output of external program, you could [fetch data using external data source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55146079/unable-to-fetch-data-using-external-data-source)